# Jquery animate enlarge/shrink a div on click (2 clicks)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to make this code stop after the first half, then when you click again it shrinks. So, 2 clicks.

How would I achieve this?

```
$('#container').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        'width': '400px',
        'height': '400px',
        'left': '90px',
        'top': '90px'
    }, 200);
    $(this).animate({
        'width': '200px',
        'height': '200px',
        'left': '90px',
        'top': '90px'
    }, 200);
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/mmk2c4vn/3/)

I have looked through all the questions related to this on Stack Overflow and none of them allowed you to click on the item that is resized.

Comment: So you just need some sort of toggling? Here is one way: http://jsfiddle.net/mmk2c4vn/4/

Comment: @Dennis Martinez: Thats it!

Comment: @Dennis Martinez: post it as a answer

Comment: @DennisMartinez you're exposing a global variable what if he did this to a lot of elements?

Comment: @Mahan It's not global if it's used properly. Who's to say he isn't going to apply this to a namespace?

Comment: a namespace is still global you can still manipulate globally, unlike putting it on the element directly you will not waste memory just for a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want that toggle effect, there are a couple different ways to achieve this.

The first way is to keep track of the "state" of the image in the application.

```
var enlarged = false;

$('#container').click(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        width: enlarged ? 200 : 400,
        height: enlarged ? 200 : 400,
        left: 90,
        top: 90
    }, 200);

    enlarged = !enlarged;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmk2c4vn/4/

The second way is to write to the data cache and keep track of the image state that way.

```
$('#container').click(function () {
    var _this = $(this),
        enlarged = _this.data('enlarged') || 0;

   _this.stop(true, false).animate({
        width: enlarged ? 200 : 400,
        height: enlarged ? 200 : 400,
        left: 90,
        top: 90
    }, 200);

    _this.data({ enlarged: !enlarged });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmk2c4vn/6/

Of course these are just two of many ways to do this.

Comment: I don't recommend your first answer

Comment: @Mahan Reasoning please?

Comment: in your first answer you're exposing a global variable, what if he does that on a lot of elements?

Comment: @ Mahan: which way has the best browser support?

Comment: @Mahan It's not global if it's used properly. Who's to say he isn't going to apply this to a namespace?

Comment: im adding it to only 2 element on a HTML page

Comment: @Dennis Martinez how can i change the left and top in your version?

Comment: @Dennis Martinez that looks great,im using it to interchange 2 graphs

Answer (score 1):

you need something to store the state on your element maybe using [data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) attribute on the element. like this

```
$('#container').click(function () {
    if ($('#container').data('state') === '0') { //check the state

        $(this).animate({
            'width': '400px',
                'height': '400px',
                'left': '90px',
                'top': '90px'
        }, 200);
        $('#container').data('state', '1'); //store the state on the element
    } else {

        $(this).animate({
            'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                'left': '90px',
                'top': '90px'
        }, 200);
        $('#container').data('state', '0'); //store the state on the element
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmk2c4vn/5/

but if you are using this a lot of time you need to use class selector and not ID's

```
$('.container').click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('state') === '0') {

        $(this).animate({
            'width': '400px',
                'height': '400px',
                'left': '90px',
                'top': '90px'
        }, 200);
        $(this).data('state', '1');
    } else {

        $(this).animate({
            'width': '200px',
                'height': '200px',
                'left': '90px',
                'top': '90px'
        }, 200);
        $(this).data('state', '0');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmk2c4vn/13/

**storing some state on your element is much better than exposing a global variable that's why i don't recommend you to create another variable just for toggling** and you can use the state for reference.

if `$('#container').data('state')`  doesnt work you can use `$('#container').attr('data-state')`

**reference**: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: btw will running 2 lots of this script with a different div work fine?

Comment: yeah it should work fine as we don't expose any global variable that an element will be dependent on it. anyways I will provide another answer that will use classes and not ids

Comment: @Mahan yeah i was just testing it and with 2 running it does not work on the first click it takes 2 click to get it running the first time

Comment: I provided an answer that you can use classes instead of ids here http://jsfiddle.net/mmk2c4vn/13/ so you can use many times

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var clicks = 0;
$('#container').click(function () {
    clicks++;
    if (clicks % 2 !== 0) {
        $(this).animate({
            'width': '400px',
            'height': '400px',
            'left': '90px',
            'top': '90px'
        }, 200);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            'width': '200px',
            'height': '200px',
            'left': '90px',
            'top': '90px'
        }, 200);
    }
});
```